# Grouping over multiple columns and counting distinct over different groups

Tags: sql, group-by

Given this data

| month | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | y |

My output should be

| month | distinct_id | total_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |

How can I achieve this in a single query?

I tried this query

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(DOCDATE,'MON') MON
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT T.MOB_MTCHED_LYLTY_ID) OVER() SHARE
from data
group by 1
```

but this is giving me an error

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You want a 3 column result, but only select 2 columns...

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select month,
    count(distinct id) distinct_id,
    count(id) total_id
from data
group by month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Month], COUNT(DISTINCT id) as dist_id, COUNT(id) as count_id
FROM data
GROUP BY Month
```

Also i should say:

1. About your code - don't use OVER if it's not necessary
2. Don't use picutes in your question like you use it know - provide data in a small table is better